# Selected row in QTreeView / QStandardItemModel

Tags: python, pyqt4

I am trying to implement an account structure (with subaccounts) in PyQt4, using a QTreeView and a QStandardItemModel. After a lot of trials and errors I have finally the tree view ready. Now, I want something to happen when I click a specific row in the tree view. My experience from the GTK toolkit suggests I would listen to some sort of signal emitted when a row is clicked and then write a signal handler to find out which row was clicked. I can't figure out how to do this in PyQt. Any suggestions?

Comment: Show us what code you have so far please.

Answer (score 2):

In class [`QtGui.QTreeView`](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/qtreeview.html) has signal [`void clicked (const QModelIndex&)`](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/qabstractitemview.html#clicked) & [`void pressed (const QModelIndex&)`](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/qabstractitemview.html#pressed) available for used. This signal function is in [`QtGui.QAbstractItemView`](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/qabstractitemview.html) Inherited by [`QtGui.QTreeView`](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/qtreeview.html).

Data from this signal is class [`QtCore.QModelIndex`](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/qmodelindex.html), so this class have [`QAbstractItemModel QModelIndex.model (self)`](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/qmodelindex.html#model) can get your model data [`QtGui.QStandardItemModel`](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/qstandarditemmodel.html).

Example;

```
import sys
from PyQt4 import QtGui

class QCustomTreeView (QtGui.QTreeView):
    def __init__ (self, parentQWidget = None):
        super(QCustomTreeView, self).__init__(parentQWidget)
        self.pressed.connect(self.myPressedEvent)

    def myPressedEvent (self, currentQModelIndex):
        # Use QModelIndex to show current data pressed
        print currentQModelIndex.column(), currentQModelIndex.row()
        print currentQModelIndex.data().toString()
        # Also can implement your QStandardItemModel here
        currentQStandardItemModel = currentQModelIndex.model()

myQApplication = QtGui.QApplication([])
myQTreeView = QCustomTreeView()
headerQStandardItemModel = QtGui.QStandardItemModel()
headerQStandardItemModel.setHorizontalHeaderLabels([''] * 4)
myQTreeView.setModel(headerQStandardItemModel)
# Append data row 1
row1QStandardItem = QtGui.QStandardItem('ROW 1')
row1QStandardItem.appendRow([QtGui.QStandardItem(''), QtGui.QStandardItem('1'), QtGui.QStandardItem('3'), QtGui.QStandardItem('5')])
headerQStandardItemModel.appendRow(row1QStandardItem)
# Append data row 2
row2QStandardItem = QtGui.QStandardItem('ROW 2')
row2QStandardItem.appendRow([QtGui.QStandardItem(''), QtGui.QStandardItem('2'), QtGui.QStandardItem('4'), QtGui.QStandardItem('6')])
headerQStandardItemModel.appendRow(row2QStandardItem)
myQTreeView.show()
sys.exit(myQApplication.exec_())
```